# Akka & SLF4J Configuration

Tags: akka, slf4j

I read the [Akka Logging tutorial](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/logging.html#SLF4J) and am still a bit confused as to how to get Akka working with SLF4J. I my *understanding* is correct, the general process is:

1. Include the `akka-slf4j` module on the runtime classpath, which transitively pulls in `slf4j-api`
2. Include an SLF4J backend on the runtime classpath, such as Logback
3. Configure the logging backend (somehow, see below)
4. Instantiate and use SLF4J loggers like normal

So first, if I have missed or misunderstood *any* of the steps above, please begin by correcting me! Assuming I'm more or less correct, I'm still completely clueless on two items:

- Do I configure Akka or do I configure the SLf4J "backend" (binding)? (see below)
- Why don't I instantiate SLF4J loggers like normal? (see below)

#### Configuration

If I were normally using SLF4J/Logback, I would just make sure that there was a `logback.xml` file on the runtime classpath. Or if I was using `slf4j-simple` I would make sure there was an `slf4j.properties` file on the runtime classpath. But with Akka, it seems that I either need to declare an `akka.loggers` section like so:

```
akka {
    loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    loglevel = "DEBUG"
    logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
}
```

...and/or configure the SLF4J binding like I normally do. **So which is it?**

#### Logger Instantiation

I don't understand why you don't instantiate SL4J loggers like normal. *Normally*, outside of an actor/actor system, my logger instantiation would look like this:

```
public class FizzBuzz {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FizzBuzz.class);

    // ...etc.
}
```

But in the Akka docs, it seems I have to instantiate them like this:

```
public class FizzBuzz {
    LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(system.eventStream(), "my.string");

    // ...etc.
}
```

**Why?!?!**

Also, bonus points if anyone can explain to me the use/purpose of "MDC values" (???) and the `DiagnosticLoggingAdapter`.

Comment: For MDC, the official docs [explain it the best](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/logging.html#MDC_values_defined_by_the_application). They also reference the Logback page explaining the concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Akka uses actors also for logging for non-blocking reasons. Every time you want to log something and uses the logger that Akka provides (like the one that is available after adding `ActorLogging` trait) it actually sends a message to the logging actor and the actor takes care to interact with the backend logging framework of your choice.

Regarding `MDC`, it is usually used to be able to filter and send data to different appenders based on some value. `MDC` stands for Mapped Diagnostic Context which means you will have a context with some values that you can use to distribute your logs in an intelligent and elegant fashion.

Comment: Thanks @hveiga (+1) - a quick follow-up regarding log configuration: do I (a) *only* use Akka logging configuration (similar to the `akka { ... }` closure above) or (b) use *both* Akka log configuration **and** `logback.xml`?

Comment: You need both. You need to set the akka logger to slf4j and then configure logback.xml for all your appenders and loggers.